# Return array of objects when a property from another array is matched

Tags: javascript

I want to filter an array

```
var arr = [{name:"james",id:10},{name:"john",id:2}];
```

What I want is to remove the items which are not in `arr` i.e. `[10,2]` using the value of `id` of the `arr` above.

I'm stuck at map

```
var filtered = arr.map(function(item){
 return //?? 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` as you stated. The filtering criterion is that `arr.id` is in `[10, 2]`.

```
const filtered = arr.filter((item) => [10, 2].indexOf(item.id) !== -1);
```

This will retain only those elements whose ID is in `[10, 2]`.

Comment: `const filtered = arr.filter(item => [10, 2].includes(item.id))` or `const filtered = arr.filter(({id}) => [10, 2].includes(id))`

Comment: is that simple? hmm

Comment: @PranavCBalan includes is `es6`? I didn't know indexOf can is a method of array, is that es2015 also?

Comment: @ThianKianPhin : arrow function is also ES6

Answer (score 0):

you can use `_.keyBy` and `_.at` to avoid callbacks

```
var res = _.chain(arr)
    .keyBy('id')
    .at([10, 2])
    .compact()
    .value();
```